# Should I manage app versioning from build.gradle or AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, react-native

I have a React Native app. It appears the version number can be defined in both build.gradle and AndroidManifest.xml.

Should I manage app versioning from build.gradle or AndroidManifest.xml and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should manage the app version from the build gradle as it overrides whatever is written in the manifest.

Comment: I could also just delete it from build.gradle and use the manifest. So is there any good reason to prefer one over the other?

Comment: See, there isnt any "specific" reason why to prefer build gradle or manifest.
some people like to update in the manifest some in the build gradle. The build gradle is just a bit more powerful. thats all. if you have "1.0" in the manifest and "1.1" in the gradle. the final outcome will be "1.1".

Comment: in what step is `AndroidManifest.xml` overwritten with the information form build.gradle?

Answer (score 0):

it is correct that you define it in build.gradle, but if you want to define it in manifest.xml, you can do it, but you must remove app version from build.gradle.
I suggest you use build.gradle.

Comment: Why though? What is the advantage or disadvantage?

Comment: @SomeGuy it is standard of gradle. but I think about flavors and buildTypes. you can change your manifest in flavors and buildtypes. but build.gradle can't change by flavors and buildtypes.